# marginal probability function for X

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

[image]

I know that $f(x,\theta) = f(x|\theta)f(\theta)$. 
I then think we can combine the terms from the α and β, with $x$ and $1-x$ but not sure how to proceed.
I would need to find the marginal before I can determine $E(X)$.

**EDITS:**

Showing what I have done before:

(a) Marginal of X

$$f(x,\theta) = f(x|\theta)f(\theta)$$

Since $\pi(\theta) \propto \theta^{\alpha-1} (1-\theta)^{\beta-1}$ then I did

$$f(x,\theta) \propto \theta^x (1-\theta)^{1-x} \theta^{\alpha-1} (1-\theta)^{\beta-1}$$
$$\propto  \theta^{\alpha+x-1} (1-\theta)^{\beta-x} $$

Therefore,
$$ f(x) \propto \int_\theta f(x,\theta) $$
$$ \propto \int_0^1 \theta^{\alpha+x-1} (1-\theta)^{\beta-x} $$
$$ \propto \frac {\theta^{\alpha+x} (-1) (1-\theta)^{\beta-x+1}}{\beta-x+1}$$
$$ \propto \frac {1}{\beta-x+1} ,  \  \ \  \ x = 0, 1$$

(b) $E(X)$ by iterated expectation
$$E(X) = E[E(X|\theta)]$$
$$  = \int_\theta E(X|\theta) f(\theta) d(\theta)$$
$$  = \int_0^1 \sum_{x=0}^1 x f(x|\theta) f(\theta) d(\theta)$$
$$  = \int_0^1 f(x,\theta)  d(\theta)$$
$$  \propto \int_0^1  \frac {1}{\beta-x+1}  d(\theta) \  \  \  \   \ 
  \   \text{[from (a) above]}$$
$$  \propto   \frac {1}{\beta-x+1} \big[\theta \Big|_0^1 $$
$$  \propto   \frac {1}{\beta-x+1} $$

Does this make sense at all?

Comment: can you include more details of where you are stuck?

Comment: So $f(x,\theta)$ is proportional to $\theta^x(1-\theta)^{1-x}\,\theta^{\alpha-1}(1-\theta)^{\beta-1}$ which you can simplify slightly.  You need to do two things: (a) remove the proportionality and (b) integrate out $\theta$ to get the marginal distribution of $X$.  I might try (b) before (a).

Comment: Thanks @siong, I added what I did, does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks @henry, I added what I did, does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your answer should be dependent on $\alpha$.
- You should not see $x$ in $\mathbb{E}[X]$.

\begin{align}
P(X=x) &= \int_0^1 f(x|\theta)f(\theta)  \, d\theta\\
&= \int_0^1 \theta^{x+\alpha-1}(1-\theta)^{1+\beta-x-1}\, d\theta\\
&= B(x+\alpha, 1+\beta -x)\\
&= \frac{\Gamma(x+\alpha)\Gamma(1+\beta-x)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta +1)}
\end{align}

Hence

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X] = P(X=1) = \frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta+1)}
\end{align}